# Rspec - Test for the assignment of a variable on POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This is the action in my controller that I'm testing.

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])

  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password]) 
    login_user!(user)
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Something was wrong with your username or password."
    render :new
  end
end
```

and this is my spec for this action

```
describe "POST create" do
  let!(:bob) { Fabricate(:user, email: "bob@bob.com") }

  it "sets user to the user with a matching email" do 
    post :create, email: "bob@bob.com"
    expect(assigns(:user)).to eq(bob)
  end
end
```

When I run this it says

```
 expected: #<User id: 1, email: "bob@bob.com", password_digest: "$2a$04$e5M21As5A6HaGBhaFsfzE.9hw4mlfYDPQbOCB9VggAI...", full_name: "Sidney D'Amore MD", created_at: "2014-07-29 15:42:02", updated_at: "2014-07-29 15:42:02">
        got: nil
```

What am I missing here? It seems to me that the HTTP request should trigger this line

```
user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
```

and assign `user` to `bob`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your action to use instance variable(`@user`). Local variable assignment cannot be tested in rspec

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])

  if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password]) 
    login_user!(@user)
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Something was wrong with your username or password."
    render :new
  end
end
```